# In PostgreSQL, is it appropriate for a deferred CONSTRAINT TRIGGER to be STABLE?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `CONSTRAINT TRIGGER` that performs a `SELECT` to determine if contract get violated. In [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) stands:

> It is inappropriate for AFTER triggers that wish to query rows modified by the current command.

I believe, that it is OK for the `CONSTRAINT TRIGGER` as long as it is deferred to the end of transaction, but I'm looking for confirmation.

Comment: Refer to the link: [TRIGGERS TO ENFORCE CONSTRAINTS](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/triggers-to-enforce-constraints/)

Comment: @CourserXu It is a valuable read, but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: A STABLE function cannot modify the database. So Trigger obviously not belong to this category.